# Neo4j with a reverse proxy and NGINX

Tags: nginx, neo4j, proxy, reverse, bolt

I'm having trouble addressing Neo4j via a reverse proxy with NGINX.

The web client works without problems, but I have no idea about the Bolt protocol.

Here's how the web client works:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name XXX;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://YYY:7474/;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }
}
```

But how does the Bolt protocol over port 7687 work?

Thanks.

PS: Google translator ftw.

Comment: can you plz post the working solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use nginx compiled with `--with-stream`. Then you can add below section to your nginx config

```
stream {
  server {
    listen 7687;
    proxy_pass neo4j:7687;
  }
}
```

Basically you need to use tcp reverse proxy and not http proxy. The above configuration section will be at top level and not inside `http` or `server` block

Comment: I have been dealing with this all week, and I am not really an Ops person. But I am frustrated beyond belief. Why cannot anyone just post the whole NGINX conf file so we can see? stream {} errors out in default.conf, where does this go??

Comment: i would much rather pay someone to do this tbh; i do math and code not ops,

Comment: @joehoeller, this is a top level config and that is where it goes. If you still have issues you can reach me [here](http://linkedin.com/in/tarunlalwani/)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to open port 7687 between your laptop and the server hsoting neo4j.

If you are using let's encrypt and try to connect though SSL. neo4j embedded certificate were not signed by an Authority which was generating the error in my chrome browser.

To make it works, I had to copy my certs in neo4j certificates :

```
sudo su 
cp /etc/letsencrypt/live/MYDOMAIN/fullchain.pem /var/lib/neo4j/certificates/neo4j.cert 
cp /etc/letsencrypt/live/MYDOMAIN/privkey.pem /var/lib/neo4j/certificates/neo4j.key 
service neo4j restart
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what works:

```
worker_processes auto;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        "" close;
        default upgrade;
    }
    
    upstream neo4j_bolt {
        server neo4j:7687;
    }
    
    upstream neo4j_insecure {
        server neo4j:7474;
    }
    
    upstream neo4j_secure {
        server neo4j:7473;
    }
    
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://neo4j_insecure;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Connection "";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
    }
    
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name localhost;
        
        #SSL/https
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl/nginx.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl/nginx.key;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl/dhparam.pem;
        
        location / {
            proxy_pass https://neo4j_secure;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Connection "";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
    
    server {
        listen 7687 ssl;
        server_name localhost;
        
        #SSL/https
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl/nginx.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl/nginx.key;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl/dhparam.pem;
        
        location / {
            proxy_pass https://neo4j_bolt;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Connection Upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
    
    server {
        listen 7688;
        server_name localhost;
        
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://neo4j_bolt;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Connection Upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
}
```

Dockerized solution here: https://github.com/joehoeller/nginx-server-neo4j-graph-db